# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (216,1) (20,1) in a neural network

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, neural-network

After following this [blog,](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/building-a-neural-network-from-scratch-using-python-part-1-6d399df8d432) ,I ran into the error while trying to change the connected neurons from [13,8,1] to [13,20,20,1]

I believe I changed all areas rightfully, I even double checked matrix multiplication by hand, please help as I am a beginner.

Below are some changes I made from the original code(which you can find in the blog linked above).

```
class NeuralNet():
    
def __init__(self, layers=[13,20,20,1], learning_rate=0.001, iterations=100):
```

> ...

```
def init_weights(self):

    np.random.seed(1) 
    self.params["W0"] = np.random.randn(self.layers[0], self.layers[1]) 
    self.params['b0']  =np.random.randn(self.layers[1],)
    self.params['W1'] = np.random.randn(self.layers[1],self.layers[2]) 
    self.params['b1'] = np.random.randn(self.layers[2],)
    self.params['W2'] = np.random.randn(self.layers[2],self.layers[3])
    self.params['b2'] = np.random.randn(self.layers[3])
```

> ...

```
def forward_propagation(self):

    Z0 = self.X.dot(self.params['W0']) + self.params['b0']
    AL_2 = self.sigmoid(Z0)
    
    Z1 = AL_2.dot(self.params['W1']) + self.params['b1']
    AL_1 = self.sigmoid(Z1)
    
    Z2 = AL_1.dot(self.params['W2']) + self.params['b2']
    yhat = self.sigmoid(Z2)
    
    loss = self.entropy_loss(self.y,yhat)

    # save calculated parameters     
    self.params['Z0'] = Z0
    self.params['Z1'] = Z1
    self.params['Z2'] = Z2
    self.params['AL_2'] = AL_2
    self.params['AL_1'] = AL_1

    return yhat,loss
```

> ...

```
def back_propagation(self,yhat):
    
    dl_wrt_yhat = -(np.divide(self.y,yhat) - np.divide((1 - self.y),(1-yhat)))
    dl_wrt_sig = yhat * (1-yhat)
    dl_wrt_z2 = dl_wrt_yhat * dl_wrt_sig

    dl_wrt_AL_1 = dl_wrt_z2.dot(self.params['W2'].T)
    dl_wrt_w2 = self.params['AL_1'].T.dot(dl_wrt_z2)
    dl_wrt_b2 = np.sum(dl_wrt_z2, axis=0)
    
    dl_sig2 = self.params['Z1']*(1-self.params['Z1'])
    dl_wrt_z1 = dl_wrt_AL_1 * dl_sig2
    dl_wrt_w1 = self.params['AL_2'].T.dot(dl_wrt_z1)
    dl_wrt_b1 = np.sum(dl_wrt_z1, axis=0)
    dl_wrt_AL_2 = dl_wrt_z1.dot(self.params['W1'].T)
    
    dl_sig3 = self.params['Z0']*(1-self.params['Z0'])
    dl_wrt_z0 = dl_wrt_AL_2*dl_sig3
    dl_wrt_b0 = np.sum(dl_wrt_z0,axis = 0)
    dl_wrt_w0 = self.X.T.dot(dl_wrt_z1)

    #update the weights and bias
    self.params['W0'] = self.params['W0'] - self.learning_rate * dl_wrt_w0
    self.params['W1'] = self.params['W1'] - self.learning_rate * dl_wrt_w1
    self.params['W2'] = self.params['W2'] - self.learning_rate * dl_wrt_w2
    
    self.params['b0'] = self.params['b0'] - self.learning_rate * dl_wrt_b0
    self.params['b1'] = self.params['b1'] - self.learning_rate * dl_wrt_b1
    self.params['b2'] = self.params['b2'] - self.learning_rate * dl_wrt_w2
```

> ...

```
def predict(self, X):
 
    Z0 = X.dot(self.params['W0']) + self.params['b0']
    AL_2 = self.sigmoid(Z0)
    
    Z1 = AL_2.dot(self.params['W1']) + self.params['b1']
    AL_1 = self.sigmoid(Z1)
    
    Z2 = AL_1.dot(self.params['W2']) + self.params['b2']
    pred = self.sigmoid(Z2)
    
    return np.round(pred)
```

exact error message is

```
    <ipython-input-68-d369d162f0f8> in forward_propagation(self)
     63         AL_1 = self.sigmoid(Z1)
     64 
---> 65         Z2 = AL_1.dot(self.params['W2']) + self.params['b2']
     66         yhat = self.sigmoid(Z2)
     67 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (216,1) (20,1)
```

note that I also changed ReLU to sigmoid

Comment: which line is the error thrown?

Comment: The errors comes from forward_propagate under z2

Comment: `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-2ab03ed07fcd> in <module>
----> 1 nn.fit(Xtrain,ytrain)

<ipython-input-68-d369d162f0f8> in fit(self, X, y)
    125 
    126         for i in range(self.iterations):
--> 127             yhat, loss = self.forward_propagation()
    128             self.back_propagation(yhat)
    129             self.loss.append(loss)
...
 `

Comment: `<ipython-input-68-d369d162f0f8> in forward_propagation(self)
     63         AL_1 = self.sigmoid(Z1)
     64 
---> 65         Z2 = AL_1.dot(self.params['W2']) + self.params['b2']
     66         yhat = self.sigmoid(Z2)
     67 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (216,1) (20,1)`

Comment: @Dorian have you had a look?